# Get the closest iframe to a parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

i am trying t get the closest iframe element to a parent element so can identify the iframe that i want to stylize with css:

```
<div class ="accroche">
  <iframe></iframe>
  <iframe></iframe>
  <iframe></iframe>
  <iframe></iframe>  
</div>
```

What would be the best technique knowing that the iframes are generated by another tool and there is no way to identify them

Comment: Define "closest" in this context.

Comment: "Parent" or what element?

Comment: get the closest iframe to the accroche div so i can add an id to it

Comment: If you mean the first of the `iframe`s you can have it with the command

`const firstIframe = document.querySelector('#accroche>iframe')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if I understand your problem it’s the first element of the list so you can do something like that in your css to style it :

`.accroche iframe:first-child{ … }`